# Alternate color dot over the letter i

Tags: css

I've been challenged with this rather silly idea.

So can I replace all "i" occurrences with `Blabla[span class=superI]i[/span]rest` : )

My idea is adding an extra (red) i "behind" the real i, and clipping the top off the real i.

Is this even possible ?

Comment: @Jerry: Can I CSS a white i into having a red dot

Comment: It really is a "silly" idea ;) can you hint a usecase, where you show this extra dot on a web-page?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Another solution http://jsbin.com/urOtixog/1/edit

This font-size can be changed.

@Fiskolin It is possible ... and quite easy.

```
<p>th<span class="i">i</span>s</p>
```

**CSS**

```
p {
  font-size: 165px;
}
.i {  
  color: red;
  position: relative;
}
.i:before {
  content: "ı";
  position: absolute; 
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work with Arial... and other fonts I suspect. Actually I can see a slither of red behind the default font you used too (Times New Roman)

Comment: Doesn't work with every font, but still pretty neat solution!

Comment: Smarter, not harder. That it doesn't handle quite Arial and Helvetica is actually the fault of the designers of those fonts I think... I've added the 3 danish "extra" vowels: http://jsbin.com/AkAyidIk/1/

Comment: To work with other fonts, use `.i:before { content:i; position:absolute; clip: rect(auto, auto, 0.35em, auto); } `

Answer (score 7):

Here's my go at it, actually using clip, with no shine-through color.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P9ZUe/1/)

HTML:

```
spec<span class="special"><i>i</i></span>al
```

CSS:

```
.special {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.special:before,
.special:after {
    opacity: 1;
    content: 'i';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font: inherit;
}
/* The 0.35 might have to be adjusted for other fonts. */
.special:before {
    color: #ff5500;
    clip: rect(auto, auto, 0.35em, auto);
}
.special:after {
    clip: rect(0.35em, auto, auto, auto);
}
.special i {
    font: inherit;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Very nice - Just what I asked for - almost perfect. If there was only a way to select based on font-family... My favorite Trebuchet MS has very small dots... Preventing selection (jsFiddle) is actually not needed, since you CAN select and copy (it's just looks funny)

Comment: @T4NK3R [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/P9ZUe/4/) for Trebuchet. I don't even have to change the `0.35em`. :)

Comment: I see a tiny "sliver?" the bottom 2 pixels of the dot in the original color (Chrome on Ubuntu) - but I did say "almost perfect" - that's very nearly perfect! - Rafaelcastrocouto only got the checkmark for doing it easier.. A bit unfair perhaps..

Comment: @T4NK3R You're right. I didn't check Chrome and the 0.35 seem to be the exact border of the dot. Setting the [clipping area to 0.4em](http://jsfiddle.net/P9ZUe/5/) from the top works in both FF and Chrome. ;) Just play around with that value a bit.

Answer (score 1):

@afaelcastrocouto's answer is brilliant, but it doesn't seem to work in all cases. This is no where near as dynamic, but you can adjust the numbers to fit your need.

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/oDePeDuw/4/edit)**

```
<p>Here is an unusual <span class="red-i">i</span>.</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
p {
  font-size: 50px;
}

.red-i {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.red-i:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  background: red;

  /* dot size */
  height: .12em;
  width: .13em;

  /* roundness */
  border-radius:.12em;

  /* position */
  position: absolute;
  top: .2em;
  left: .05em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an interesting approach - giving more freedom for designing the dot. But it's a quite fragile across different fonts. Letting .red-i inherit font-size and font-family helps though : )

Answer (score 0):

Adding a second red dot really is a "silly idea" probably with no use-case :)

But something similar was occurring to me:

I found a beautiful font "Kingthings Xander" for parts of my site, which is missing the german umlauts ä,ö,ü, so I added a span around each single umlaut like

```
<span class="umlaut">ä</span>
```

and added the [diaeresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)) with this CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: kingthings_xander, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 17px;
}
.umlaut:before {
  margin-left:2px;
  content: "¨";
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```